# Phone stuck in bootloop due to HiFont

Tags: root-access, boot-loop

My phone has stuck in a bootloop when it rebooted after installing a font using HiFont. I have tried HiFont many times, it works well. It is for the first time it happened. The phone boots up and shows the whole animation but gets stuck on the last frame. Please suggest me a good solution.

- Android version: **4.1.1 Jelly Bean**
- Mobile manufacturer: **Micromax**
- **Rooted**
- Model: **Bolt A61**

**Hard reset and wipe cache partition are not working.** *Typing* **ls** *in adb shell inside the* **/system/font** *gives the following output*[image]

Comment: Of course they don't. The fonts are contained within the **System** partition. Only reinstalling the firmware will fix this issue.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Don't discourage me. There could also be some solution using the ADB. Please help me.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the system fonts are comprised by the Roboto family. For this motive, I recommend you to obtain the content of the **/system/fonts** folder via `ls`, issued from **adb**, and to update your question with the output of ls. This way, we could start to know how HiFont works, and, thus, conceive a way to solve the issue. The hard way would be to download one firmware suited for your phone, move it to the SD card (or the internal SD via **adb**), and flash it via recovery.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Sorry for the delay, but I update my answer. Please help me.

Comment: @Izzy Any clues to offer, aside from a firmware reflashing, guru?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman well, he has access to root shell, can't he just delete the most recent font?

Comment: @AaronGillion Hey man, will it solve the problem.

Comment: Yup. Do you remember what the name was?

Comment: @AaronGillion It may work, but I recall that these "font customizer" apps often replace the Roboto family with the font family chosen by the user, and then rename it to match the Roboto names. Such approach wouldn't work, if that's the case with HiFont.

Comment: @AaronGillion Do you think that it is due to any damaged font? If so, I had already copied the fonts from there, before the phone stuck in this hell - the Boot loop.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman I did it. Aaron Gillion helped me. It was not possible without your help. Thank you DeathMaskSalesman.

Comment: @Aman Glad to hear that you were able to solve the issue.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Thank you. It was not possible without you. You were the only one who showed me the way in the dark.

Comment: @Aman Heh, it's Aaron, who put my theory into practice.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yes, that's right. But you were also somewhere involved in my success. No more arguments, just a big Thanks. You are great. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to ADB with root, you can easily remove the font you installed using this command:

```
rm /system/fonts/xxxxx.TTF
```

If you don't have the slightest clue which fonts were yours, you can actually sort `ls` output by date modified, as so:

```
ls -tr
```

...which will show the most recent fonts at top, given the modified dates are correct.

If your most recent font is of the Roboto family, that means your customizer app replaced the default font! You'll have to write down the exact filename, remove it, and `cp` another font (eg. Arial) and `rename` it to the same filename. Of course, none of this will be needed if you have a device backup. Just copy the originals.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: I am about to try it.

Comment: How to copy the fonts from my computer(S:\fonts\*.ttf) to the /system/fonts using adb.

Comment: `adb push s:\RobotoLight.ttf` then `cp /sdcard/Roboto.ttf /system/fonts/Roboto.ttf`

Comment: ADB push is not working. It is showing the help menu.

Comment: You have to exit the shell first, so there's no # or $ when you type. Or just open a new command prompt window. Try adding the destination `/sdcard` to the end of it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. You are great. Thanks. Thanks. Thanks.